# Unable to upgrade legacy account with launch.stellar.org

Tags: accounts, operations, wallets, history, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my legacy account using the method listed in the FAQ:

https://www.stellar.org/community/faq#how-do-i-upgrade-from-the-old-network

To upgrade from the old network, log in here: https://launch.stellar.org/

But when I log in it says my lumens will be sent to an account without a key and "An error occured." :(

[image]

Anyone know what I can do?